# how can use $_SERVER to get all link or number of #post

Tags: php

My links are like this

http://sitename.com/test/t9.html#post23

I want to get the full link from the browser, or get only number of the post from it

I've tried:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But this show me only before the hash

```
http://sitename.com/test/t9.html#post23
```

i want get all link or the number after hash `23`

Comment: Everything after the hash is not sent to PHP. You'd need to use javascript to utilize / send it to PHP.

Comment: "parse_url" that is working good , but how i get all link to use it parse_url("http://sitename.com/test/t9.html#post23",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);

Answer (score 0):

The anchor (`#`) section of the URL is not passed through to PHP, so you'll be unable to get access to it as you're expecting.

You'll need to use javascript to grab it like this:

```
<script>alert(window.location.hash);</script>
```

And perhaps then use ajax to send that through to your PHP

Comment: thnx brother ,i'm not good in ajax ... can you write all code or another way to get post number

Comment: How about you try and write the code yourself? This isn't a place to just ask for code.

Comment: thnx brother , i already write all my code but only this part is a problem for me . and i said to you i'm not good in ajax , so how i write something i don't know about it

Comment: tbh when you need the anker in your php script you've done something wrong.

Comment: @Pinki , Yeah but this script not mind " i'm not make it "

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` should actually work i think ;)

Comment: i try it already ,show me befor hash only

Comment: Well, i have no answer then i guess, here the Link to php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: thnx , i try them all but no one get after hash